# How to get back button to return to same position in UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which has a segue set up to send the user to a new VC, when any of the cell is selected in the table. This segue works fine. The new VC has a "Back" button that sends the user back to the table, but this button always sends the user back to the top of table. Is there any way (perhaps programmatically) to get the back button to return the user to the table, but at the cell they previously selected (ie halfway down the table)?

Comment: Are you reloading the table on `viewDidAppear(_:)`/`viewWillAppear(_:)`?

Comment: @NicolasMiari the table is reloaded by calling a queryandappend function in the `viewDidLoad()`. The back button segue has no code associated with it. Just set up on the main storyboard

Comment: The back button may not have code directly associated with it, but the view controller's methods are automatically called as the view hierarchy changes. If you only reload your table view in `viewDidLoad()`, however, you should be OK...

Comment: Set a breakpoint in (for example) `tableview(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` to see if it is called on back. Also, what happens with row deselection on returning? (`clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property).

Comment: @AlekPiasecki, Go with Nicoas Miari's solution. But if you really need the table to reload at other delegate method of Viewcontroller like willAppear, didAppear, then keep the index of click and write code to move the table to the particular row. Hope it will be helpful

Comment: @NicolasMiari You said I should be "ok". What do you mean? And is it wise that I call the reloading of the tableview in `viewDidLoad()` instead of `viewDidAppear()`?

Comment: I meant, your table view should be in the same state you left it

Comment: viewDidLoad is called only once

Comment: @Janmenjaya but that is part of the question... how do I code to move the table to that row? I have the indexPath.row value passed to the VC from the tableVC, since I use it for an iteration. How do I code to move the table to that row when it comes back?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I see. That makes sense. Would recommend reloading the table in `viewDidAppear` if the app is used to show user posts since `viewDidLoad` would only do it once and new posts could be put while the user is on the app?

Comment: @AlekPiasecki, you can do that by this line of code. : [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:indexPath.section] 
             atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];

Comment: @Janmenjaya and this would go in the `viewDidAppear()` of the tableviewcontroller?

Comment: @AlekPiasecki, If you are reloading table the write this line after the table reload. Yes may be in didAppear, that depend on your code how you have managed the data to display. Write in didAppear, most probably it will work, then let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add this as an answer.

**Code :**

```
 [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:indexPath.section] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
```

Before this line of code, you need to keep track of the index path that you clicked, so that you can pass the indexPath in the parameter to move your table to required position.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same situation. Then

1. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` ,i am remembering cell selected to `indexPathSelected`
2. I am reloading tableview from  `viewWillAppear`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

3. I am scrolling tableView to the position from `ViewDidAppear`

```
 [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathSelected 
                  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

otherwise  same behaviour you can get very easily with the help of `contentOffset` ,and you can reuse it when you came back.